Is it wise of me to continue learning about philosophy?
I know this question isn't exactly about philosophy, I am not quite sure what tag to use. Perhaps it is better suited for some psychological forum but I think there is a fair chance that someone here might relate to this and provide their perspective and maybe helpful tips.
I think I have a somewhat unhealthy obsessional attitude towards philosophical problems. It manifests in various ways, but mainly it makes focusing and enjoying much harder. For example I was doing my homework and I got distracted thinking about philosophy and began reading articles instead of doing the work. Or I am watching a show and I pause mid episode because I am thinking about philosophy and the flow of the show is ruined.
I have this itch to resolve the problem, I feel uncomfortable and maybe even anxious when I feel like I don't know the solution. And then I stumble across some article or video that is convinces me that some particular viewpoint is correct and I feel relieved and at peace. Then I either start doubting the solution or move on to another problem and the cycle begins again.
As I said I often change which philosophy problem I am currently focused on. In the past it were Which theory of mind is correct? What epistemological theory is correct? Which interpretation of quantum mechanics is correct? What is the definition of naturalism? What is the foundation of mathematics? What is the definition of scientific method?
I don't think the concrete problem really matters, I feel like I can develop this obsession basically about any unresolved topic. I was reading a bit on the internet and I don't want to self-diagnose but some type of OCD seems pretty close to what I am experiencing. I like philosophy but maybe I am just psychologically unfit for it.
Do you have any advice for me?

I'd recommend therapy. This doesn't seem particularly specific to philosophy - people can and do have similar relationships with any other topic. People might get distracted thinking about anything, really, and they may feel an itch to solve a programming problem, or some puzzle, or a challenge in a video game, etc. If it's causing you problems, a therapist would be the best person to help you navigate that. For what it's worth people with autism get really "into" their interests, while people with ADHD struggle to stay focused on things (but both of those have a bunch of diagnostic criteria).
